# Copy GitHub project including items

Tags: github, github-api-v3, github-projects

GitHub provides a [project board called GitHub Projects](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/learning-about-projects/about-projects).

I want to move a project from my personal account to an organization account including any items (cards/issues/PRs) that are part of the project.

As far as I have seen, GitHub Projects doesn't allow moving projects but it's certainly possible to copy projects.

[image]

That copy feature allows creating a copy of the projects but it will neither copy issues nor pull requests nor project workflows, even though I can duplicate issue drafts.

[image]

After copying the project, all my issues/PRs are not part of the copied project.

Is there a way to copy a GitHub project without losing the existing items?